# Cross-Origin XHR failed in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am doing cross origin XHR in popup page like this:

```
// popup.js
var some_url="http://****";
$.get(some_url, function(){
    // do something here
}).error(function(){});
```

And here's the permissions in my manifest: ( I wrote "<all_urls>", but after  published to Chrome Web Store, it becomes following)

```
"permissions": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ]
```

The problem is that, sometimes the XHR works fine, but **sometimes**(e.g. relaunch the browser, switch to another computer) I got the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://****. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://****' is therefore not allowed access.
```

By the way, when I use the unpacked version under Developer mode, the XHR seems to work properly always.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make cross domain requests until the other server you are requesting to allows you.

As a response to your request, server is going to send a list of 'allowed recipients'. If it allows you in the list, then the browser will show you the response otherwise the error that you are getting will be shown.

In dev mode, it works probably because the servers allows everyone in dev mode for say, testing purposes.

Comment: I am not clear how the server would know the request was from an unpacked extension or an extension installed from the web store.

Comment: most probably, the unpacked extension sends data(behind the scenes) that tell server that request is from dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

If it works sometimes but not other times without you changing any code it's probably a bug with Chrome. You can file a bug report at [crbug.com/new](http://crbug.com/new).

Comment: I installed the extension on my desktop and my laptop, it works on my laptop but sometimes fails on my desktop. I will file a bug report for this.